# How to change keys from a map in scala

Tags: java, scala, functional-programming, purely-functional

How to change the following keys from the map without any variables full functional

```scala
HashMap(false -> List(20, 15, 20, 17), true -> List(50, 25, 45, 21, 100, 2000, 2100))
```

to

```scala
HashMap("String1" -> List(20, 15, 20, 17), "String2" -> List(50, 25, 45, 21, 100, 2000, 2100))
```

I tried with map and was able to change the keys to the same strings but not to different  ones.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can apply a map to all the items but focus only on the keys:

```scala
yourMap.map({ case (a, b) => (f(a), b) })
```

You can define `f` to be a function or simply a constant map e.g.:

```scala
Map(false -> "String1", true -> "String2")
```

Putting it all together:

```scala
object HelloWorld {
   def main(args: Array[String]) {
        val m = Map(false -> List(20, 15, 20, 17), true -> List(50, 25, 45, 21, 100, 2000, 2100))
        val f = Map(false -> "String1", true -> "String2")
        val x = m.map({ case (a, b) => (f(a), b) })
        System.out.println(x)
   }
}
```

Yields the expected result:

```
Map(String1 -> List(20, 15, 20, 17), String2 -> List(50, 25, 45, 21, 100, 2000, 2100))
```

If you like one-liners you can also avoid a separate map / function:

```scala
yourMap.map({
  x => x match {
    case (false, v) => ("String1", v)
    case (true, v)  => ("String2", v)
  }
})
```

Yet another way is to only treat the left side of the tuple:

```scala
yourMap.map({case (a, b) =>
  (a match {
     case false => "String1"
     case true  => "String2"}, b)})
```

And just for completeness, if your only elements really are `true` and `false` you can just do:

```scala
yourMap.map({case (a, b) => (if (a) "String2" else "String1", b)})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a [pattern matching anonymous function directly](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/08-pattern-matching.html#pattern-matching-anonymous-functions):

```scala
hashM
  .map {
    case (true, ints) => "String1" -> ints
    case (false, ints) => "String2" -> ints
  }
```

if you work with non-exhaustive pattern matching i.e. you also want to filter out safely some tuples from the collection then use `collect` :

```scala
hashM  
  .collect {
    case (true, ints) => "String1" -> ints
  }
```

you'll get here:

```scala
Map(String1 -> List(50, 25, 45, 21, 100, 2000, 2100))
```

It's probably the most readable solution i can think of.